# R how to calculate 'Percentage of Change' between two rows?

Tags: r

- I like to compute 'Percentage of change between two rows' while Item
  changes in rows.
- For first row of items, I am ok to place some text or blank
  (example ‘skip’ or blank is ok) because of no comparison of previous row for same
  item

  ```
  df <- data.frame(period=rep(1:4,2), 
               farm=c(rep('A',4),rep('B',4)), 
               cumVol=c(1,5,15,31,10,12,16,24), item=c(rep('Z',3),rep('Y',3),rep('X',2)),
               other = 1:8);
  ```

My desired out put of 'Percentage_Change' column (additional column to dataset) would be like below. (Formula: 100/Previous Item row value * current row Item value...Example for 2nd row..100/1 * 5 = 500)

```
Row Percentage_Change
1   Skip
2   500
3   300
4   Skip
5   32.25806452
6   120
7   Skip
8   150
```

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I am ok to skip the first row with no text or blank or zero

Comment: Can you check the 5th value?

Comment: 5th Value is wrong. It suppose to be 32.25. Seems like it calculating only above 100%.

Comment: Can you show how you got that value?

Comment: 5th value is ....100/31 (4th row value) * 10 (5th row value) = 32.25

Comment: I changed the code.  Used only 'item' as group.  Now it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `shift` from `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDt(df)`), grouped by 'item', we get the "Row" from `.I` and create the "Percentage_Change" by dividing the "cumVol" by the `lag` of "cumVol" (got by `shift`) and multiplying by 100.  If needed the grouping column can be removed by assigning (`:=`) it to NULL.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, list(Row = .I, Percentage_Change=round(cumVol*
   (100/shift(cumVol)),2)), .(item)][, item := list(NULL)][]
#   Row Percentage_Change
#1:   1               NA
#2:   2           500.00
#3:   3           300.00
#4:   4               NA
#5:   5            32.26
#6:   6           120.00
#7:   7               NA
#8:   8           150.00
```

NOTE: This gives NA for elements where there are no comparison, instead of the `Skip`.

Comment: @Akrun..can you help me in 5th value please? I did overlooked that value.

Comment: @Murali It is changed.  Please check

Comment: I just tested the code on my big dataset and worded perfect for less than 100 values. Great job and I love you :-)

Comment: How could you apply this to categories -1 and 1 for `% change <= .8` and `% change >= 1.2` and also to look back at values for the past hour instead of just the last row

Comment: @zsad512  Please post as a new question as your comment is not clear to me

Comment: @akrun https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46084728/breaking-a-continuous-variable-into-categories-using-dplyr-and-or-cut/46086107?noredirect=1#comment79135217_46086107

Answer (score 5):

The same can be done with `dplyr`. This is completely analogous to [akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3732271/akrun)'s answer, but uses other syntax.

```
library(dplyr)
mutate(df, Row = 1:n()) %>%
  group_by(item) %>%
  mutate(Percentage_Change = cumVol/lag(cumVol) * 100) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(Row, Percentage_Change)
## Source: local data frame [8 x 2]
## 
##     Row Percentage_Change
##   (int)             (dbl)
## 1     1                NA
## 2     2         500.00000
## 3     3         300.00000
## 4     4                NA
## 5     5          32.25806
## 6     6         120.00000
## 7     7                NA
## 8     8         150.00000
```